# Access parameters from an object listed in a listbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, listbox, listboxitem

I have several classes in my program and I'm using Windows Form to create the objects from the different classes and list them in different listboxes.

Right now I have a form with all the listboxes (Form 1) and another form (CreerVoiture) where i put all the info to create my selected object.

[image]

[image]

An example is when i click on the button "Voiture!" my second form opens, when I add all the info and push on "Ajouter" it adds the object to the listbox selected.

Code from Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreerVoiture creervoiture = new CreerVoiture();
        if (creervoiture.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the contents of form2's TextBox.
            Voiture voiture = new Voiture(creervoiture.GetMarque(), creervoiture.GetPrix(), creervoiture.GetConsommation(), creervoiture.GetReservoir());
            this.list_voiture.Items.Add(voiture);

            this.list_voiture.DataSource = null;
        }
        creervoiture.Dispose();
    }
```

What I would like to know is how I can access a parameter I added in my second form once I added it to the listbox.

I was thinking to use something like:

```
list_voiture.SelectedItem.Prix
```

Prix is a getter from my class Voiture

```
public double Prix
    {
        get { return this.prix; }
        set { this.prix = value; }
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to be possible. Is this possible and if so, how?

Thanks in advance,

Jeremy

Comment: Use `ListBox.Items` to iterate over all the items in the ListBox. If you need only the SelectedItem, then use `ListBox.SelectedItem` Property. Also, you need to cast the Property to `Voiture` and then access the properties.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.
Could you elaborate your answer a little more, I don't know what you mean with cast the property to Voiture.
Thanks

Comment: `var selectedItem = list_voiture.SelectedItem as  Voiture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of object is `Voiture` then you can cast the object to that type:

```
Voiture voiture = (Voiture)list_voiture.SelectedItem;
double prix = voiture.Prix;
```

Or in one line:

```
double prix = ((Voiture)list_voiture.SelectedItem).Prix;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to the forms and so still a bit confused.
I added a button on my form that if i click on it it should write the price (Prix) of the car in Label1.
`private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double prix = ((Voiture)list_voiture.SelectedItem).Prix;
            label1.Text = prix.ToString();
        }
`
But it doesn't work. Nothing is happening when I click on the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nevermind it worked :) I forgot to link the method to my button... Thanks for the info!